# Rails 3 + Authlogic + Passing three parameter for validating the User

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.2, authlogic

In my authlogic, I am trying to pass three parameter to validate the user ie ( email, dob, passowrd) because email address is not unique through the system.

But I am not getting the way to validate it because Authlogic takes two parameter for creating sessions.

Comment: Can you post a bit more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

At last, I am done with this implementation.

**Steps for doing this :**

Step 1 - In our controller (for example, `class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController`):

```
login = {:dob => dob_date, :email => primary_email }
@user_exist = UserSession.new(:email => login, :password => password)
if i@user.save
    redirect_to "/UserDashboard"
    return
end
```

---

Step 2. Change in UserSessionModel

```
class UserLoginSession < Authlogic::Session::Base

    find_by_login_method :find_by_user_email_or_date_of_birth

end
```

---

Step 3 : Change in UserModel

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.login_field = :email # email is the login field
    c.validate_login_field = false 
          # There is no login field, so don't validate it
    c.validations_scope = :dob
  end

  def self.find_by_user_email_or_date_of_birth(login)
    dob = login[:dob]
    primary_email = login[:email]
    find_by_email_and_dob(primary_email, dob)
  end      
end
```

---

This is one of the way to provide 3 parameters while using authlogic for authentication.